# Deprecation Warnings hanging Vue app build

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, deprecation-warning

I am getting a plethora of `Deprecation Warnings` related to various CSS issues that are hanging my app build.

Here is the last one before the build hangs.

```
Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(24, $fortnightly-font-size) or calc(24 / $fortnightly-font-size)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
39 │     'size': #{24 / $fortnightly-font-size}rem,
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-fortnightly/preset/variables.scss 39:15  @import
    stdin 1:9                                                                           root stylesheet

⠙  Building for production...Warning: 13 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Warning: 24 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

⠴  Building for production...Warning: 13 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

⠇  Building for production...
```

The process just hangs at this point. It does nothing even after being left for 30 minutes plus.

I have had warnings before but they never blocked the `npm run build` from completing.

If anyone has any pointers on how to get past this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: [Its a known issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+Deprecation+Warning:+Using+/+for+division+outside+of+calc()+is+deprecated+and+will+be+removed+in+Dart+Sass+2.0.0+site:stackoverflow.com). Things changed, so use `"sass": "1.32.13",`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue.